# How to copy a closure function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, code-duplication

> **[UPDATE]** It turns out that I totally misunderstand scope of closure: The answer is here:
>
> [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
>
> **Example 7 answer my question**, very helpful.

===================================================================

All:

I wonder how can I make a copy of a closure function like:

```
function closure(){
    var cv = "closure variable";
    function changecv(newcv){
        cv = newcv;
    }
    changecv.getcv = function(){return cv;}
    return changecv;
}
```

Say I have another function to duplicate this closure function:

```
function dupclosure(cFn){..... I do not know how to do this...}
var newclosureFn = dupclosure(closure);
var cf1 = closure();
var cf2 = newclosureFn ();
cf1("new closure variable");
console.log( cf2.getcv() );  // still "closure variable"
```

Thanks

Comment: `var cf2 = closure();` - http://jsfiddle.net/xskdamsp/

Comment: @Andreas  Thanks. So if I want to share that cv variable and still with this closure function pattern, how can I do that? Using prototype(I thought prototype is only for object prototype chain, so I can not just use cv, I have to use closure.prototype.cv, right?)?